# How to cook chicken franks?

Tags: chicken, sausages

I have some chicken franks (sausages). How do I properly/completely cook them to include them in spaghetti and omelettes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can imagine a few ways of doing it based on the texture you're looking for, and what you have to work with.

- Remove the meat from the casing and fry the meat in a pan.  You'll basically be cooking ground meat which will allow you to easily seasons it and also integrate it into other foods.  This method also allows you to season the actual meat if you want to.
- Cut the sausages into disks and fry them in a pan.  This will leave you with more body than the first method, and also allow you to really get some good color on the flat parts of the cut sausage.
- Leave them whole, poke holes in them, and cook them on anything.  I wouldn't do this for the application you're looking for.  You will eventually be cutting them up, and if you cut them after cooking, you won't have the browning that you could have had.

Answer (score 3):

Punch various holes in the sausage to prevent them from bursting. Then you can either grill them, boil them or sauté them according to your preference.

The sausages have already been cooked in the factory, so you only need to reheat.

Comment: All sausages aren't cooked in the factory. If the OP is really talking about franks (hot dogs), they are, but sausage can come raw.

Comment: @scientifics, I presumed the OP knows what he's talking about. What factory sausages aren't cooked? Don't fresh sausages normally come from the butcher?